# In ruby on rails devise, will setting config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false results in cross-site request forgery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, csrf

This post gives a tutorial on how to sign in with ajax using devise and rails.
http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/

One of the changes is to set config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false

My friend told me that this will result in cross-site request forgery but he's not sure why. Does anyone know if this is true and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this modification doesn't lead to CSRF. It just tells Devise that HTTP headers should be returned (or not) for AJAX requests.

Comment: but what does that mean exactly?

Comment: The [devise tests](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/test/failure_app_test.rb#L284) help explain. When `http_authenticatable_on_xhr` is false, Devise will return a 302 redirect response to the login page and/or the `WWW-Authenticate` header on unauthenticated requests. When you set it to true, Devise will instead just return a 401 response (without that header).